# A multivariable calculus exercise in the weak formulation of the Navier Stokes Equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

The following is an excerpt from Robinson's [An introduction to the classical theory of the
Navier–Stokes equations](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masdh/Campinas.pdf).

[image]

Here (1.1):
[image]

Using integration by parts I can get the $(\nabla u,\nabla\varphi)$ term from the second term of (1.1). But I don't get $\int_0^T(u,\varphi_t)$ and $-(u_0,\varphi)$. Also, the signs in (1.8) are confusing. Would anyone help me to derive (1.8) from (1.1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sign is wrong in the pressure term.

The integration by parts in time gives
$$
\int_0^T (u_t,\varphi)=(u(T),\varphi(T))-(u(0),\varphi(0))-\int_0^T (u,\varphi_t)=
-(u(0),\varphi(0))-\int_0^T (u,\varphi_t).
$$

The correct formula should be
$$
\int_0^T[(u,\varphi_t)-(\nabla u,\nabla\varphi)-((\nabla\cdot u)u,\varphi)-(\nabla p,\varphi)]dt=-(u(0),\varphi(0))
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is because $\phi(0,x)$ is not necessarily zero, so 
$$\int_0^T\int_\Omega u_t\phi=-\int_0^T\int_\Omega u\phi_t+\int_\Omega u_0\phi(0,x).$$

Comment: I don't see how the signs match. Would you elaborate?

Comment: According to your calculation, I got $-\int_0^T(\nabla p,\varphi)$ on the LHS of  (1.8) and $(u_0,\varphi(0,x))$ on the RHS.

Comment: Yeah, it just seems you have everything multiplied by $-1$, but it's all the same.

Comment: What I meant is I got: $$\int_0^T(u,\phi_t)-(\nabla u,\nabla \phi)-((u\cdot\nabla)u,\phi)-(\nabla p,\phi)=(u_0,\phi). $$ Not the one in (1.8).

Comment: I see the issue I think, in there statement I believe it should be $(p,\nabla\phi)$, not $(\nabla p,\phi)$, they should have integrated by parts with the pressure term.

Comment: Or if they're not integrating by parts there, then the pressure sign should be different

Comment: That is what I thought. How about the $(u_0,\phi)$ term?

Comment: That's correct, when you take it to the RHS it should have the same sign as the $(u,\phi_t)$.

Comment: do you miss a minus sign in front of the term $(u_0,\phi)$?

Comment: Oh wait, yes I think I did